# SVN Checkout issue from Repository

Tags: svn, locking, svn-checkout

In our project we have a piece of code to checkout the contents from the
server. While checking out it given error as "svn:Can not create a new File
'/home/dev761/TAPS/mydocs/.svn/lock'  . Please, can any body tell the
reason what is the problem ?

Comment: Do u have write permission to mydocs directory.

Comment: yes. 
But interesting is happening in my code but i cant believe it, i.e i can checkout the file when i ran the application in debug mode but when i executed normally it shows me above error. i am wondering whats wrong in it.

Comment: @JavaLearner you still need to check permissions to /home/dev761/TAPS/mydocs/ and it's childs.

Comment: I double checked the permission, its fine. I also changed the location to tmp directory(system tmp folder), same issue raised.